# Are function parameters evaluated in a C# null-conditional function call?

Tags: c#, expression-evaluation, null-conditional-operator

Are function arguments always evaluated in a C# null-conditional function call?

i.e. in the following code:

```
obj?.foo(bar());
```

Is bar evaluated if obj is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1177-null-conditional-member-access) specifies that

> A `null_conditional_member_access` expression `E` is of the form
> `P?.A`. Let `T` be the type of the expression `P.A`. The meaning of
> `E` is determined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - If `T` is a non-nullable value type, then the type of `E` is `T?`, and the meaning of `E` is the same as the meaning of:
>
>   ```
>   ((object)P == null) ? (T?)null : P.A
>   ```
>
>   Except that `P` is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise the type of `E` is `T`, and the meaning of `E` is the same as the meaning of:
>
>   ```
>   ((object)P == null) ? null : P.A
>   ```
>
>   Except that P is evaluated only once.

In your case, `P` is `obj`. `A` is `foo(bar())`. If we expand both cases:

```
((object)obj == null) ? (T?)null : obj.foo(bar())

((object)obj == null) ? null : obj.foo(bar())
```

By [the semantics of the ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1115-conditional-operator), when `obj` is null, the third operand, `obj.foo(bar())` will not be evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

Running test code indicates that in the Microsoft compiler at least the arguments are not evaluated, however the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) doesn't seem to specify this as required behaviour.

Comment: Quote from your link: _The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. That is, if one operation in a chain of conditional member or element access operations returns null, the rest of the chain doesn't execute. In the following example, B is not evaluated if A evaluates to null and C is not evaluated if A or B evaluates to null: `A?.B?.Do(C);`_ Does that not cover it?

Comment: At second glance, you asked about _function_ arguments. I agree that is not specifically discussed. Given that quote, though, I would expect the same behavior for function arguments as for non-function arguments.

Comment: It's worth noting that the link isn't to the actual specification - it's the language reference. The spec is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1177-null-conditional-member-access or (source) https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#1177-null-conditional-member-access

Comment: What you've linked to is the language reference, *not* the spec. When you're seeking precision, the spec is what you should be looking at. I was just finding the right part to quote but [Sweeper beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73730746/15498)

Answer (score -1):

No.

There is no reason to evaluate `bar()` if `obj` is null.

Create the example, in dotnetfiddle or elswhere, and make `bar` output something. Nothing will be outputed.